# Laravel 4, reset password only with token (howto check it and get user)

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

What is the best way to reset password only with token?

Now it mades with token and email, I want to get an email by checking tocket in reminders table.

Thanks!

**Update**
Resolved this by:

$email = DB::table(Config::get('auth.reminder.table'))->where('token', $token)->pluck('email');

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Usually the process of resetting the password is the following: user enters email. An email with a link containing the token is sent to the specified address. The user clicks the link and he is redirected to a form to enter his new password. Then the password is reset. Have you followed any tutorial? Have you tried any code? Please show what have you tried and what does not work for you.

Comment: In tutorial we have a link with token and form. In that form we have 3 fields: email (!), password and password_confirmation. So, I don't want to use thin email field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I do password resets.

1. User clicks Forgot Password link and is taken to a form with one field for email.
2. They enter their registered email address and I check the email exists in the DB. If it does, I store a random reset code for that user using Str::random(60). I then save the user and email them a link with a reset code (eg. http://domain.com/reset/CODE).
3. User clicks the link and is taken to the URL above which checks the CODE. If the CODE exists in the DB, the password for the matching user is reset to something random using Str::random(10) and this new password is mailed to the user.

Not sure if this is right/wrong, but it works for me.

Comment: Yes, it's okay. But I'm learning and using Laravel's native API for Auth and manipulation with passwords (Auth, Password, etc.). Thanks any way. And solution I've posted in Update section in question

Comment: Okay, awesome. Glad to hear you found a solution.

Comment: And I've described, that I need possibility to have same email on different accounts. So I made another modifications :)